# Parametric equation of sinusoidal curve around semi-circle for radius 0.75

Tags: computer-science, parametric, plane-geometry, visualization

Hi I need some help with my assignment. I can't seem to understand what the questions are asking for. Would really appreciate explanations too. Thanks so much!

[Question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUV3Y.png)

I cant seem to figure out if i should look at it from a 2d or 3d point of view. Or should i think of it as a slinky?

Comment: Do you understand rotational transformation of coordinates?

Comment: @anton Sherwood no i do not

Comment: I asked that question before seeing ganeshie8's answer, which doesn't need it, so never mind.

Comment: Oh and to your last questions, a third dimension won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is your assignment I'll give few hints.

- $(r\cos t, r\sin t)$ gives a semi circle for $0\le t\le \pi$ as $\color{blue}{x^2+y^2} = r^2\cos^2t + r^2\sin^2t = \color{blue}{r^2}$.
- $r$ is the distance from center, so if you want to vary it sinusoidally, just add the corresponding waveform to $r$.
- Say $r'=r+\sin(nt)$, then $(r'\cos t,r'\sin t)$ puts the waveform $\sin(nt)$ around the circle.
- Play with [this desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fkcwmufwer) to get a feel visually.

Comment: Thank you! Using your hints i managed to solve it!

Comment: glad to hear you figured it out yw:)